# Insert values into new columns using values from old columns without locking table

Tags: postgresql

The premise is simple - a table has a `jsonb` column; this `json` value always has three fields, so I decided to split the three fields into three separate columns on the same table.
Since the table is really large (in the ~100m range), I need a way to insert these `json` values into their own respective columns without locking the table.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what a synchronized second server run the query there and let the sychronosation take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid locking. Keep your transactions short and the number of rows locked reasonable by performing the update in batches, e.g. by primary key range. That reduces the danger of deadlocks.

Comment: Indeed. I'd suggest writing a stored procedure for doing batch updates for a range of the table so you can fiddle around a bit with the batch size to find a sensible number (which depends on your use case. If you only have writes every few seconds, a batch update taking a few seconds could be acceptable, for example)